# Nashorn: Strange returning of packages

Tags: javascript, java-8, nashorn

In Java's Nashorn engine, when you eval code, if you do this

```
var e = Packages.org.bukkit["event"]
```

e will be null.

But, one thing that I found, is that if I do this

```
var anothervar = Packages.org.bukkit.event
var e = Packages.org.bukkit["event"]
```

e (as well as anothervar) will be the org.bukkit.event package.

Why does Nashorn have it so after I access a package with dot notation, it will start working with the bracket notation?

Comment: Don't use an image to sum it up. Put the text in your question.

Comment: @meagar I just edited it. I find it really... dumb (for a lack of a better word) how people on here downvote a question just because it's worded improperly. They can simply help it by either suggesting edits, or commenting on it (just like you did), instead of simply downvoting it.

Comment: Uh, because that's one of the main purposes of downvotes. Hover your mouse over the down arrow on any question, and you'll see that "it is unclear" is one of the main criteria for downvoting. A downvote doesn't mean "you suck" or "get lost", it expresses the opinion that your question is either not well-written, or not useful, or doesn't show sufficient effort, or a combination thereof. And you only received one downvote. Anyway, the question is much improved after the edit. I just cast the fourth reopen vote, one more and it will be reopened.

Comment: @AdiInbar I recieved two downvotes, but that's neither here nor there. And although I do see the criteria, In my ideals, I believe it should be used AFTER the OP reads the comments on it being unclear, but still refuses to change it. I'm about giving people a chance.

Comment: 1. Downvotes are intended as an opinion on the quality of the question at the time the vote is cast, not as a punishment for bad behavior. I do think some people are too quick to downvote, but I don't agree that if something deserves a downvote, the vote shouldn't be cast until the poster has had a chance to respond to a comment. The idea of requiring comments for downvotes has been discussed and roundly rejected. I'm not saying necessarily that your question deserved the downvote, just that I don't agree with that principle. 2. As of this writing, you've received one downvote and one upvote.

Comment: Also note that downvotes aren't permanent. They can be retracted or even converted to upvotes if the question is improved (although downvoters don't always revisit the question). (For the record, the only vote I cast on this question was to reopen.)

Comment: @AdiInbar 1. I undestand. 2. Yes, but that's as of now. Originally, it was two downvotes.

Comment: @AdiInbar I know that votes can be changed, but the part in parentheses of your second sentence, "although downvotes don't always revisit the question" is the issue I've been having. I haven't been on here long enough to get a feel for the people on here, but from my experience on other places, that happens a lot of the time.

Comment: If there were originally two downvotes, that's a case in point for what I'm saying. One of the downvoters must have retracted his downvote after you improved the question. See, the system works. :)

Comment: @AdiInbar I know, I know :)

Comment: Okay, +1 for being responsive to advice and turning this into a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I am looking at, it is a [Java 8 bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8031715), so in the meantime, a hackish workaround can be eval-ing the package with the dot notation

e.g.

```
eval("Packages.org.bukkit."+"event.server"); //or whatever variable it may be
```

**EDIT**

The bug has been fixed, so it should work now.